# Difficulty with Celery: function object has no property 'delay'

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, celery, flask-security

I have been churning through the software development recently and have had some success bending celery to my will.

I have used it successfully to send emails, and have just tried to use almost exactly the same code (after restarting all processes etc) to send sms through Twilio.

However I keep getting the following issue:

```
File "/Users/Rob/Dropbox/Python/secTrial/views.py", line 115, in send_sms
send_sms.delay(recipients, form.text.data)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'delay'
```

My code is as follows:

```
@celery.task
def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender)
    for email in recipients:
        msg.add_recipient(email)
    msg.body = text_body
    mail.send(msg)

@celery.task
def send_sms(recipients, text_body):
    for number in recipients:
        print number
        num = '+61' + str(number)
        print num
        msg = text_body + 'this message to' + num
        client.messages.create(to=num, from_="+14804054823", body=msg)
```

send_email.delay when called from my views.py works perfectly, however send_sms.delay fails every time with the above error.

Any help on troubleshooting this is appreciated.

-- As requested:

```
@app.route('/send_mail', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@roles_accepted('Admin')
def send_mail():
    form = SendMailForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            emails = db.session.query(User.email).all()
            list_emails = list(zip(*emails)[0]) 
            send_email.delay('Subject', 'sender@example.com', list_emails, form.text.data)
    return render_template('send_generic.html', form=form)

@app.route('/send_sms', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@roles_accepted('Admin')
def send_sms():
    form = SendMailForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            recipients = db.session.query(User.mobile).all()
            list_recipients = filter(None, list(zip(*recipients)[0]))
            send_sms.delay(list_recipients, form.text.data)
    return render_template('send_generic.html', form=form, send_sms=send_sms)
```

My send_sms celery decorated function is showing up as a registered task:

```
(env)RP:secTrial Rob$ celery inspect registered
-> celery@RP.local: OK
    * app.send_email
    * app.send_security_email
    * app.send_sms
```

and for config I am simply using the guest:rabbitmq

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest@localhost//'
```

Comment: can you post your celery config and views?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The view name `send_sms` conflicts with the celery task name. The name `send_sms` references the view, not the task, when used in the module that contains the view.

Use different name to avoid the overwriting.